# Ruby: split each 3 array members to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby array:

```
array1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I need to turn it to a multi-dimensional array splitting each its consequent 3 (or less if last) members into a sub-array:

```
array2 = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`each_slice` is what you're looking for

```
array1.each_slice(3).to_a
 => [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```